# Android : how to capture a image of GPS location

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am using Google Maps for finding the location on a provided address.

I want to store the image of location which I get from Google Maps `onClick`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code for google map & storing onClick

```
public class TestGPSActivity extends MapActivity 
 {    
MapView mapView;
private MapController mc;
private GeoPoint p;
private double lng;
private double lat;
private Address address;
private View mCurrentUrlMask;
private File imageFile; 

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
            boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.pin);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
        return true;
    }
} 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
{   
    //---when user lifts his finger---
    if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
        GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                (int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY());

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    p.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

            String add = "";
            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
            {
                for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); 
                        i++)
                    add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
            }

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {                
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return true;
    }
    else                
        return false;
}             


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps_main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView); 

    mapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


     // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + GPSActivity.DIRECTORY;   

    // create bitmap screen capture
    Bitmap bitmap;

    View v1 = mapView.getRootView();

    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    OutputStream fout = null;
    imageFile = new File(DemoCamGPSActivity.DIRECTORY);

    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("in file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();


    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {   

        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(getIntent().getStringExtra("address"), 1);

    } catch (IOException e) {



    }

    try{ 
        address = addresses.get(0);  
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        flash("Unable to locate given address");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GPSMainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    try{
      lng  = address.getLongitude();
      lat  = address.getLatitude();   

      GPSActivity.writeLog(getIntent().getStringExtra("address") +" GPS co-ordibnates : "+lat+" , "+lng);
    }catch (Exception e) {


    }


    p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 

    //---Add a location marker---
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

    mapView.invalidate();
    mapView.invalidate();        
}
private void flash(String data) {   
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    return false;
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GPSMainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}    
 }
```

I am getting this error

```
03-28 16:54:12.580: E/AndroidRuntime(30010): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mentha.Demo/com.mentha.Demo.TestGPSActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am getting error on this perticular codes

```
   // create bitmap screen capture
    Bitmap bitmap;

    View v1 = mapView.getRootView();

    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    OutputStream fout = null;
    imageFile = new File(DemoCamGPSActivity.DIRECTORY);

    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("in file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath));
```

Please help me out.. thanks in advance

Comment: take a screenshot of the current View

Comment: @imrankhan I am trying to take screenshot of particular view but unable.. please view my code.. i have updated question with code.. Thank you in advance

Comment: on this line--- View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();

Comment: Well nullPointerException => something is null... mCurrentUrlMask is null you should initialise it or define what view it is...

Comment: @Ferdau thanks sir -- I have initialise to mapView.. same error I am getting now on other line --  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());

Comment: Why is v1 the mapviews rootview? Rootview probably is null

Comment: @Ferdau -- if i make it null... its throwing nullpointerException on that perticular line..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9403/discussion-between-rahul-and-ferdau)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I was having problem with image capturing of GPS location. I have just created the capture menu, In which after uploading the GPS location one can capture the image by clicking on capture menu button.

Here is the whole code for capturing the screenshot of GPS location & how to find GPS location.

```
public class TestGPSActivity extends MapActivity 
{    
MapView mapView;
private MapController mc;
private GeoPoint p;
private double lng;
private double lat;
private Address address; 

//google Map
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
            boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.pin);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
        return true;
    }
} 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
{   
    //---when user lifts his finger---
    if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
        GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                (int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY());

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    p.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

            String add = "";
            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
            {
                for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                    add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
            }

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {                
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return true;
    }
    else                
        return false;
}             

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps_main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {   

        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(getIntent().getStringExtra("address"), 1);

    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{ 
        address = addresses.get(0);  
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        flash("Unable to locate given address");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GPSMainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    try{
        //stores the Longitude n lattitude in log file
        lng  = address.getLongitude();  
        lat  = address.getLatitude();   

        //for writing into log.text
        HomeActivity.writeLog(getIntent().getStringExtra("address") +" GPS co-ordibnates : "+lat+" , "+lng);

    }catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 

    //---Add a location marker---
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

    mapView.invalidate();

    //mapView.invalidate();      
}   

//ScreenShot of Image
private void screenshot() {
    try{
        String mapDIR = HomeActivity.DIRECTORY+"/Image";

        File f = new File(mapDIR);

        if(! f.exists())
        {
            f.mkdir();
        }

        MapView v1 = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mapDIR+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
            b.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, fos);
            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void flash(String data) {   
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    return false;
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GPSMainActivity.class));
        finish();
    } 
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}     
//menu button
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) 
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, 1, 0 , "Exit");
    menu.add(0, 2, 0 , "Capture Image");



    return true;
} 

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case 1: 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GPSMainActivity.class));
        finish();
        break; 
    case 2: 
        screenshot();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Captured Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break; 
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
}
```

Thanks for All.. Hope this will help some one..

Comment: go through this blog -- http://findgpslocation.blogspot.in/ you ll get info about how to find gps location.

Answer (score 4):

Could using static maps be the solution you were looking for?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: its give all details of google map.. I want to know how i can implement in my code..??how should i store the image in jpeg or png format..??? please help me out.. thank you

Comment: Just use this URL: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=ghent&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false and change 'ghent' with the address or try with coordinates, just read the link I gave you properly... You can add markers and stuff... Just google how to save an image from an url.